# Best way to serialize a boolean representing a reverse lookup

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have some models that look like the following, where I would like to serialize `Parent` with a boolean field representing whether an associated `Child` reverse lookup exists.

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    ... some fields

class Child(models.Model):
    parent_fk = models.OneToOneField(
        "Parent",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="child",
    )
    ... some other fields

class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    has_child = serializers.BooleanField()
    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = ["has_child", ... some fields]
```

These are the solutions I've tried and what I understand to be the problems with them

- just add `"child"` to `fields` - this inserts the value of the foreign key?
- use `SerializerMethodField` - triggers a DB lookup for each row?

Is there a clean way to implement this feature?

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate the `Parent` with an extra attribute:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

Parent.objects.annotate(
    has_child=Exists(Child.objects.filter(parent_fk_id=OuterRef('pk')))
)
```

You can add this as `queryset` to the `ViewSet`, `ListAPIView`, etc.

The `Parent` objects that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.has_child`.